# docker microservice apps restart over and over again in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

I am trying to run microservice applications with kubernetes. I have rabbitmq, elasticsearch and eureka discovery service running on kubernetes. Other than that, I have three microservice applications. When I run two of them, it is fine; however when I run the third one they all began restarting over and over again without any reason.

One of my config files:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hrm
  labels:
    app: suite
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8086
      nodePort: 30001
  selector:
    app: suite
    tier: hrm-core
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hrm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: suite
        tier: hrm-core
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: privaterepo/hrm-core
        name: hrm
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8086
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regsecret
```

Result from kubectl describe pod hrm:

```
 State:     Running
      Started:      Mon, 12 Jun 2017 12:08:28 +0300
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 +0000
      Finished:     Mon, 12 Jun 2017 12:07:05 +0300
    Ready:      True
    Restart Count:  5
  18m       18m     1   kubelet, minikube               Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hrm" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 10s restarting failed container=hrm pod=hrm-3288407936-cwvgz_default(915fb55c-4f4a-11e7-9240-080027ccf1c3)"
```

kubectl get pods:

```
NAME                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
discserv-189146465-s599x    1/1       Running   0          2d
esearch-3913228203-9sm72    1/1       Running   0          2d
hrm-3288407936-cwvgz        1/1       Running   6          46m
parabot-1262887100-6098j    1/1       Running   9          2d
rabbitmq-279796448-9qls3    1/1       Running   0          2d
suite-ui-1725964700-clvbd   1/1       Running   3          2d
```

kubectl version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.4", GitCommit:"d6f433224538d4f9ca2f7ae19b252e6fcb66a3ae", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-05-19T18:44:27Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.0", GitCommit:"fff5156092b56e6bd60fff75aad4dc9de6b6ef37", GitTreeState:"dirty", BuildDate:"2017-04-07T20:43:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

minikube version:

```
minikube version: v0.18.0
```

When I look at pod logs, there is no error. It seems like it starts without any problem. what could be the problem here?

edit: output of kubectl get events:

```
19m        19m         1         discserv-189146465-lk3sm    Pod                                      Normal    SandboxChanged            kubelet, minikube       Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
19m        19m         1         discserv-189146465-lk3sm    Pod          spec.containers{discserv}   Normal    Pulling                   kubelet, minikube       pulling image "private repo"
19m        19m         1         discserv-189146465-lk3sm    Pod          spec.containers{discserv}   Normal    Pulled                    kubelet, minikube       Successfully pulled image "private repo"
19m        19m         1         discserv-189146465-lk3sm    Pod          spec.containers{discserv}   Normal    Created                   kubelet, minikube       Created container with id 1607af1a7d217a6c9c91c1061f6b2148dd830a525b4fb02e9c6d71e8932c9f67
19m        19m         1         discserv-189146465-lk3sm    Pod          spec.containers{discserv}   Normal    Started                   kubelet, minikube       Started container with id 1607af1a7d217a6c9c91c1061f6b2148dd830a525b4fb02e9c6d71e8932c9f67
19m        19m         1         esearch-3913228203-6l3t7    Pod                                      Normal    SandboxChanged            kubelet, minikube       Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
19m        19m         1         esearch-3913228203-6l3t7    Pod          spec.containers{esearch}    Normal    Pulled                    kubelet, minikube       Container image "elasticsearch:2.4" already present on machine
19m        19m         1         esearch-3913228203-6l3t7    Pod          spec.containers{esearch}    Normal    Created                   kubelet, minikube       Created container with id db30f7190fec4643b0ee7f9e211fa92572ff24a7d934e312a97e0a08bb1ccd60
19m        19m         1         esearch-3913228203-6l3t7    Pod          spec.containers{esearch}    Normal    Started                   kubelet, minikube       Started container with id db30f7190fec4643b0ee7f9e211fa92572ff24a7d934e312a97e0a08bb1ccd60
18m        18m         1         hrm-3288407936-d2vhh        Pod                                      Normal    Scheduled                 default-scheduler       Successfully assigned hrm-3288407936-d2vhh to minikube
18m        18m         1         hrm-3288407936-d2vhh        Pod          spec.containers{hrm}        Normal    Pulling                   kubelet, minikube       pulling image "private repo"
18m        18m         1         hrm-3288407936-d2vhh        Pod          spec.containers{hrm}        Normal    Pulled                    kubelet, minikube       Successfully pulled image "private repo"
18m        18m         1         hrm-3288407936-d2vhh        Pod          spec.containers{hrm}        Normal    Created                   kubelet, minikube       Created container with id 34d1f35fc68ed64e5415e9339405847d496e48ad60eb7b08e864ee0f5b87516e
18m        18m         1         hrm-3288407936-d2vhh        Pod          spec.containers{hrm}        Normal    Started                   kubelet, minikube       Started container with id 34d1f35fc68ed64e5415e9339405847d496e48ad60eb7b08e864ee0f5b87516e
18m        18m         1         hrm-3288407936              ReplicaSet                               Normal    SuccessfulCreate          replicaset-controller   Created pod: hrm-3288407936-d2vhh
18m        18m         1         hrm                         Deployment                               Normal    ScalingReplicaSet         deployment-controller   Scaled up replica set hrm-3288407936 to 1
19m        19m         1         minikube                    Node                                     Normal    RegisteredNode            controllermanager       Node minikube event: Registered Node minikube in NodeController
19m        19m         1         minikube                    Node                                     Normal    Starting                  kubelet, minikube       Starting kubelet.
19m        19m         1         minikube                    Node                                     Warning   ImageGCFailed             kubelet, minikube       unable to find data for container /
19m        19m         1         minikube                    Node                                     Normal    NodeAllocatableEnforced   kubelet, minikube       Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
19m        19m         1         minikube                    Node                                     Normal    NodeHasSufficientDisk     kubelet, minikube       Node minikube status is now: NodeHasSufficientDisk
19m        19m         1         minikube                    Node                                     Normal    NodeHasSufficientMemory   kubelet, minikube       Node minikube status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
19m        19m         1         minikube                    Node                                     Normal    NodeHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet, minikube       Node minikube status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
19m        19m         1         minikube                    Node                                     Warning   Rebooted                  kubelet, minikube       Node minikube has been rebooted, boot id: f66e28f9-62b3-4066-9e18-33b152fa1300
19m        19m         1         minikube                    Node                                     Normal    NodeNotReady              kubelet, minikube       Node minikube status is now: NodeNotReady
19m        19m         1         minikube                    Node                                     Normal    Starting                  kube-proxy, minikube    Starting kube-proxy.
19m        19m         1         minikube                    Node                                     Normal    NodeReady                 kubelet, minikube       Node minikube status is now: NodeReady
8m         8m          1         minikube                    Node                                     Warning   SystemOOM                 kubelet, minikube       System OOM encountered
18m        18m         1         parabot-1262887100-r84kf    Pod                                      Normal    Scheduled                 default-scheduler       Successfully assigned parabot-1262887100-r84kf to minikube
8m         18m         2         parabot-1262887100-r84kf    Pod          spec.containers{parabot}    Normal    Pulling                   kubelet, minikube       pulling image "private repo"
8m         18m         2         parabot-1262887100-r84kf    Pod          spec.containers{parabot}    Normal    Pulled                    kubelet, minikube       Successfully pulled image "private repo"
18m        18m         1         parabot-1262887100-r84kf    Pod          spec.containers{parabot}    Normal    Created                   kubelet, minikube       Created container with id ed8b5c19a2ad3729015f20707b6b4d4132f86bd8a3f8db1d8d79381200c63045
18m        18m         1         parabot-1262887100-r84kf    Pod          spec.containers{parabot}    Normal    Started                   kubelet, minikube       Started container with id ed8b5c19a2ad3729015f20707b6b4d4132f86bd8a3f8db1d8d79381200c63045
8m         8m          1         parabot-1262887100-r84kf    Pod          spec.containers{parabot}    Normal    Created                   kubelet, minikube       Created container with id 664931f24e482310e1f66dcb230c9a2a4d11aae8d4b3866bcbd084b19d3d7b2b
8m         8m          1         parabot-1262887100-r84kf    Pod          spec.containers{parabot}    Normal    Started                   kubelet, minikube       Started container with id 664931f24e482310e1f66dcb230c9a2a4d11aae8d4b3866bcbd084b19d3d7b2b
18m        18m         1         parabot-1262887100          ReplicaSet                               Normal    SuccessfulCreate          replicaset-controller   Created pod: parabot-1262887100-r84kf
18m        18m         1         parabot                     Deployment                               Normal    ScalingReplicaSet         deployment-controller   Scaled up replica set parabot-1262887100 to 1
19m        19m         1         rabbitmq-279796448-pcqqh    Pod                                      Normal    SandboxChanged            kubelet, minikube       Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
19m        19m         1         rabbitmq-279796448-pcqqh    Pod          spec.containers{rabbitmq}   Normal    Pulling                   kubelet, minikube       pulling image "rabbitmq"
19m        19m         1         rabbitmq-279796448-pcqqh    Pod          spec.containers{rabbitmq}   Normal    Pulled                    kubelet, minikube       Successfully pulled image "rabbitmq"
19m        19m         1         rabbitmq-279796448-pcqqh    Pod          spec.containers{rabbitmq}   Normal    Created                   kubelet, minikube       Created container with id 155e900afaa00952e4bb9a7a8b282d2c26004d187aa727201bab596465f0ea50
19m        19m         1         rabbitmq-279796448-pcqqh    Pod          spec.containers{rabbitmq}   Normal    Started                   kubelet, minikube       Started container with id 155e900afaa00952e4bb9a7a8b282d2c26004d187aa727201bab596465f0ea50
19m        19m         1         suite-ui-1725964700-ssshn   Pod                                      Normal    SandboxChanged            kubelet, minikube       Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
19m        19m         1         suite-ui-1725964700-ssshn   Pod          spec.containers{suite-ui}   Normal    Pulling                   kubelet, minikube       pulling image "private repo"
19m        19m         1         suite-ui-1725964700-ssshn   Pod          spec.containers{suite-ui}   Normal    Pulled                    kubelet, minikube       Successfully pulled image "private repo"
19m        19m         1         suite-ui-1725964700-ssshn   Pod          spec.containers{suite-ui}   Normal    Created                   kubelet, minikube       Created container with id bcaa7d96e3b0e574cd48641a633eb36c5d938f5fad41d44db425dd02da63ba3a
19m        19m         1         suite-ui-1725964700-ssshn   Pod          spec.containers{suite-ui}   Normal    Started                   kubelet, minikube       Started container with id bcaa7d96e3b0e574cd48641a633eb36c5d938f5fad41d44db425dd02da63ba3a
```

Comment: Just an optimistic guess, exit code 137 means kill signal 9 (subtracting 128)  so there might be not enough memory on the node. Process might be killed by the OS. Do you have a chance to increase number of nodes or reduce number of other services to see if it helps?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but when I describe node it seems there is enough memory. it says:

OutOfDisk   False
MemoryPressure  False
DiskPressure   False
Ready   True
Now I'm thinking there might be a problem about discovery service.

Comment: Does it matter which order you start them in, for example is it always `hrm` that fails to start, or if you start them in another order is it always the third ? This would imply a resource issue, as per the other comments.
I noticed that the server is 1.6.0, given that was the first 1.6 release have you tried with a server that is 1.6.4 ?

Comment: Hi @DanMurphy There is no order, as you said it is always the third. It looks like a resource problem but according to the output of the describe node command everything seems to be fine. it is really baffling. I installed kubectl via curl and I could not find anything about how to upgrade the server version. Can you help me further about it?

Comment: Hi @DanMurphy I found out how to upgrade so I will try 1.6.4 and get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: did you try 'kubectl get events' to see if you find something meaningful?

Comment: @AshishVyas as far as I can see there is nothing unusual. I will add the output to the question. Also upgrading to 1.6.4 didn't work.

Comment: I do see "System OOM encountered" in events.

Comment: @AshishVyas oh yes, it slipped my eye. I also noticed that if I don't do anything on the microservices, nothing crashes. But when I click on one of the functions on the app, the problem begins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See kubectl get logs for any obvious errors. In this case, as suspected, it looks like it is insufficient resources problem (or a service that has resource leaks). 
If possible, try increasing resources to see if it helps.

Comment: I will try to start minikube with more memory. I'll update the issue after that. Thanks!

Comment: hi @AshishVyas it is indeed a memory problem. they seem to be working without any issues right now. thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help you.